# Include a lstlistings keyword in lstlistings caption

Tags: listings, inline, keywords

I'm writing a small summary for my fellow students about VB in LaTeX. I have to cover the basic loops and found the `\lstlistnigs` package to be the best for writing colored code. I have already added some keywords that are not included directly in the package.
I have also defined a short verb for inline listing.
Now, what I would like to do, is to include a VB keyword in a listing's caption with the help of a inline listing.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{ language=[Visual]Basic,  
keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen}, stringstyle=\color{Maroon},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,  
frame=lines, showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,  
tabsize=3,
aboveskip=10pt,
belowskip=10pt,
lineskip=3pt,  
numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt  
morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Console, Double, ByVal}}

\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize]{\|}

\begin{document}

Here, we can see an example of the |If| loop implementation with the |ElseIf| and |Else| statements.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={|If| loop with |Else If| and |Else|},label=ifloop]  
If [cond] Then  
    [code]  
ElseIf [cond] Then  
    [code]  
Else  
    [code]  
End If  
\end{lstlisting}  

\end{document}
```

I hope I have described the problem thoroughly and will be grateful for any tips!

Cheers

Comment: @Pjanc_Matuzl You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ["Section 5.1 Listings inside arguments"](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf). You can use `\lstinline` and need to add an additional backslash before the backslash, the braces and the space.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=[Visual]Basic,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
  stringstyle=\color{Maroon},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  frame=lines,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  tabsize=3,
  aboveskip=10pt,
  belowskip=10pt,
  lineskip=3pt,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Console, Double, ByVal},
}

\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize]{\|}

\begin{document}

Here, we can see an example of the |If| loop implementation with the
|ElseIf| and |Else| statements.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={%
  \lstinline|If| loop with \lstinline|Else\ If| and \lstinline|Else|%
},label=ifloop]
If [cond] Then
    [code]
ElseIf [cond] Then
    [code]
Else
    [code]
End If
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works!
I have, however, improved it to my needs (which are writing as little as possible) by defining a simple command:
    \newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline|#1|}